# How can i login to facebook account from remote server

Tags: php, facebook

From a while i was able to login to my facebook account from remote server using curl by this code

```
$email = "YOUR_EMAIL";
$pass = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
$login = array('email' => $email,'pass' => $pass,'login' => 'Log In');
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'https://m.facebook.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$login);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,'');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.27309/34.1445; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

but now i can't do it.
Any ideas

Comment: What do you mean by you can't ?? Did you get any errors ?

Comment: Why not use the API?

Comment: Facebook works actively to prevent you from accessing the site in an automated fashion outside of the Graph API. You're likely getting stymied by a captcha or an IP block on your server or something.

Comment: There is no way to get over the captcha ?? @ceejayoz

Comment: @Snatch The entire point of stuff like captchas is to prevent you from getting around them. You're doing stuff Facebook doesn't want you doing - don't be shocked when they stop you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution to login through a pre-created facebook application then here is what you need to follow.

---

First of all

Download [facebook-php-sdk-v4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4)

or if you are using composer (ignore this step otherwise) then the alternate and easy installation is

```
{
  "require" : {
  "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "~5.0@dev"
  }
}
```

and run the composer update command.
You just need to set everything up.

---

Start the session and include the autoload file

```
// Pass session data over.
session_start();

// Include the required dependencies.
require('/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v5/autoload.php' );

//Now initialize the facebook PHP SDK instance 
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret'            => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);
```

Now that everything is setup. You just need to call the appropriate functions on the **$fb** object that we just created

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
// $permissions = ['']; Add any permissions if applicable
$callback    = base_url().'customer/facebook_return';
$loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);
```

Now that PHP part is done. You finally need to create a UI button for logging in with facebook.

```
<a href="<?=$loginUrl?>" class="my-btn" >Login Through Facebook</a>
```

Further more there is a great article written by Ben Marshall, which you can follow for further guidance

Visit : https://benmarshall.me/facebook-php-sdk/

Have a good day :-)